# Compare objects in Array List

Tags: c#, sorting, collections, compare

I have an arraylist with objects and their properties. Is there a way to compare the properties of the objects?

**Update** Below is the list example

```
listTA = {(ID, MonAry[], RequestDate), (ID, MonAry[], RequestDate)};
```

Comment: Yes, but please provide some example data (input and desirable results of comparation)

Comment: Yes.

(Your question is so vague I don't even have a guess about what you're trying to ask)

Comment: A code sample would really help here.

Comment: The answer is yes. But you should define your preferred output so that the correct "yes" answer can be supplied.

Comment: I've updated the question. Hope its clear now.

Comment: You need to use IComparer as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @Ye Myat Aung There are a lot of scenario's still in which you are using comparisons. Sorting? Filtering? If checks on two elements in the array? etc.. What are you trying to achieve, so that we can know the comparison you are looking for. :)

Comment: Sorry if I made the question not clear. What I'm trying to do is, I want to compare two objects and take the better one. What I really need to compare is that values of arrays of that each object.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new Class Implementing `IComparer` Interface. then you can sort your list by calling `myList.Sort(new MyComparer());` and you can compare each one with other one using new `MyComparer().Compare(firstOne, secondOne);`

sample :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class SamplesArrayList  {

   public class myReverserClass : IComparer  {

      // Calls CaseInsensitiveComparer.Compare with the parameters reversed.
      int IComparer.Compare( Object x, Object y )  {
          // you can implement this method as you wish! cast your x and y objects and access to their properties.
          return( (new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).Compare( y, x ) );
      }

   }

   public static void Main()  {

      // Creates and initializes a new ArrayList.
      ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
      myAL.Add( "The" );
      myAL.Add( "quick" );
      myAL.Add( "brown" );
      myAL.Add( "fox" );
      myAL.Add( "jumps" );
      myAL.Add( "over" );
      myAL.Add( "the" );
      myAL.Add( "lazy" );
      myAL.Add( "dog" );

      // Displays the values of the ArrayList.
      Console.WriteLine( "The ArrayList initially contains the following values:" );
      PrintIndexAndValues( myAL );

      // Sorts the values of the ArrayList using the default comparer.
      myAL.Sort();
      Console.WriteLine( "After sorting with the default comparer:" );
      PrintIndexAndValues( myAL );

      // Sorts the values of the ArrayList using the reverse case-insensitive comparer.
      IComparer myComparer = new myReverserClass();
      myAL.Sort( myComparer );
      Console.WriteLine( "After sorting with the reverse case-insensitive comparer:" );
      PrintIndexAndValues( myAL );

   }

   public static void PrintIndexAndValues( IEnumerable myList )  {
      int i = 0;
      foreach ( Object obj in myList )
         Console.WriteLine( "\t[{0}]:\t{1}", i++, obj );
      Console.WriteLine();
   }

}
```

another IComparer sample :

```
private class sortYearAscendingHelper : IComparer
{
   int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
   {
      car c1=(car)a;
      car c2=(car)b;
      if (c1.year > c2.year)
         return 1;
      if (c1.year < c2.year)
         return -1;
      else
         return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 If the OP is needing the comparison to sort, this is a great answer. :)

Comment: how should I do if I want to compare values inside the array(MonAry[]) with another object's MonAry[] ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the SO post,

[Arraylist can't compare objects after they are loaded from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711401/arraylist-cant-compare-objects-after-they-are-loaded-from-disk)

Check the tutorial blog for either using `IComparable` OR  `IComparer2`

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Beginners_Sort.aspx#IComparablevsIComparer2

Thanks